# user control form in EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

We have created the user control in C# and added it to the EA through API

Repository.AddWindow("Addin View", "Framework.MyEAControl") as MyEAControl;

```
namespace Framework
{
    [Guid("2F8CD700-575C-41F3-91C8-D269376AC0D9")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MyEAControl.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyEAControl: UserControl
    {
        public MyEAControl()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();


        }
}
}
```

But the api is returning null .When EA is opened it is throwing objectrefrence not set to an instance of an object exception in EA

But in EA they are telling that Once the custom control has been created and registered on the target system, it can be added using the AddWindow() method of the Repository object.

But how to register on target system

Comment: Have you read http://bellekens.com/2011/01/29/tutorial-create-your-first-c-enterprise-architect-addin-in-10-minutes/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you register for COM interop.
There should be a checkbox somewhere in the build options of your dll project that will do that for you.

If you don't use that you can also use regasm.exe to register your dll for COM interop.

I have a working example add-in on [github](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/tree/master/MyAddin) and a bunch of articles on how to write add-ins for Enteprise Architect on my [website](http://bellekens.com/writing-ea-add-ins/)